# TypeScript: failure to resolve signature of generic class decorator

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I can't understand why TypeScript needs explicit generic type definition for `Child2` and `Child3` in this case:

```
abstract class Base {
    public static A: string = "Fallback_A";
    public DoSmthWithClassName(): string {
        return "Fallback_DoSmth";
    }

    constructor(...args: any[]); // overload for type consistency with children
    constructor(x: string)
    { }
}

// typeof any non-abstract child of Base
type BaseType = typeof Base & (new(...args: any[]) => Base);

// decorator, modifies methods and static properties
function ClassDecorator<T extends BaseType>(valueA: string): (value: T) => T {
    return (value: T) => {
        value.prototype.DoSmthWithClassName = () => value.name + ".DoSmth." + value.A;
        value.A = value.name + valueA;
        return value;
    }
}

@ClassDecorator("Foo") // OK
class Child0 extends Base {

}

@ClassDecorator("Foo") // OK
class Child1 extends Base {
    constructor(x: number) {
        super(x.toString());
    }
}

@ClassDecorator("Foo") // Unable to resolve...
class Child2 extends Base {
    static X: number = 0;
}

@ClassDecorator<typeof Child3>("Foo") // OK
class Child3 extends Base {
    static X: number = 0;
}
```

Comment: If the decorator return type is changed to void, then the snippet runs without error but compiler still resolves generic type to BaseType in every case, and I don't understand why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that TS can't infer the type of T from the only parameter `valueA`. What you want is the generic parameter on the inner/returned function:

```
// decorator, modifies methods and static properties
function ClassDecorator(valueA: string) {
    return function <T extends BaseType>(value: T): T {
        value.prototype.DoSmthWithClassName = () => value.name + ".DoSmth." + value.A;
        value.A = value.name + valueA;
        return value;
    }
}
```

Your version isn't causing any issues with Child0 and Child1 because they are structurally identical to base.

Comment: I undestood your idea, however i decided to drop generics and use this kind of decorator:
`function ClassDecorator(valueA: string): (value: typeof Base) => void` because compiler assumes that `value.prototype.DoSmthWithClassName` type is `any` in generic case.

Answer (score 0):

It's way too late to answer and I don't know if it still fit the need. But, without the need for a generic parameter inside ClassDecorator, you can still instantiate Child2 with a 'static X' in it and access X by `Child2.X`.

This is due to the fact that a ClassDecorator without a constructor is like an experienced sailor without a ship and it needs a Type so that Typescript can be sure about compiling it to a function.

A best solution would be to reflect it after the ClassDecorator,

```
const Reflected = (value:string) : ClassDecorator => {
  return reflected => { 
    // `reflected` here is `Type<Foo>`, not `Foo`
    console.log(`The reflected:  ${reflected}`)
  };
};
```

and straight away you can use it since the @Reflected("Foo") is not a new instance,

```
//@ClassDecorator("Foo") // Unable to resolve...
@Reflected("Foo")
class Child2 extends Base {
  public static X: number = 0;
  
}
```

Some reasons I can think of:

- A class, basically a javascript function at run time,  is way too much generic but a constant instance is not (focused on type) and thats why we need a ClassDecorator for 'dependency injection' and other benefits.
  -In Typescript We need a type of 'decorated' instance, not the instance itself during design time and it provides the right type during compile time.

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FDCGCMGcBcCdQMbQAQIDakpZAhTBTZAb2GWQAcBXcNASwWRlGnuQEEAuRuWgOwHNkAXmQAiAGKg0acIgDWAfTaiA3KQrU6DACIB7AMoBbaAAsA6rVMBhDFgByoQ-gAUASi4xYfQSTJ-ksPjQlLC8YpLSsgiKekamquoAviBkCLq8npRIurDOAHQFoLD8kFygvACeANoAuq4qyAD0jci6AG74sGi6oAAmyABmOcjQFeSEaRm0MPi8CBXIAO6WJqgmtGi9gbzqk5nZuQAeHjwCrupEyMnJwM0jY-i6A8jlC7zpALQQnogoCOubVrPPCQfDAUbjXAEAAqD2E93GTyhoOQADJkM5ePhFvlCsVSi9KrVXMIAHzI-D1EDUu69fBpeDQHIAGmQhl0vVoA1o+GwTlMHOw5X6TBYDHIsF041gLF5wAGlDmLHSyBsmEg2npOWYOQAPNDkPhDtBZr1sCD8LDxqTnG0pJR8JxuF4zlxbfb8FxoSShOSDb4AkEQmF3WgHV6feSA-47WH8HkJbomRD47FjOYVmr7I5CCI3GTkLGHXleDnkABqMR5NOmPKiCuFj15NhqfxkIvxtjwjslsuVjst9T+QLBUKNuOtq7AG57FAAJXwAzQ9JN-TzHY4nm8JK4WY1WsZw19xHUI+DIyK-CCBcuQ6aLQABtBL0EH8gTJ1CNNkA+rfhdeIui6KSD6su8KAPoBugPneey6MueTdPwzgPgA5IES4rvgvSoQWXDIAAJEQz7FEEiQPuc-hwQhSHOCRV7QJRVxqIkaggAAAnumoMjquQSEBogkncADyADSwDoOqqoAr0AAMhrGqa5oECe04cVxB68c4-G6IJ97IGJEm2NgVgyQAjApJq8GaFInqk6T7EyRxcLwlCGOAnQktGfiQJQ0rOIceRMvopzIa4VJkNcIDNJxxncdqTnaVBel3AAqqWNCEEygaQPBHQFHkwDsQumFINhSUCecklYNJGy9AATJZSm2QGVA0KwoqsAAGi5bkebA8KyZOalFSVy5lb0FW6VVxm1Zs9VzhZRpWTZpl1Y1rWaB1z5isgACavXuZ0g2TrOsBZIlXnIHevn+UxyRkCNRUaTxTm6imSJrZsADMNo6SlLSGdVJkyd9TXWcpKIBp1DA9cgrlHQNIhDSN1HxrRD5dS8KBfQ18JEbj9V5F15FVQ58Ho7oyGY9jc0NYt+NEITi3E6TwDM2ZxPwmZKNo4hVMoV1zigAMJoDeqtD8Lw260xzjMc6zFHAEAA)

PS: if you're using 'reflect-metadata' package you can see further with `console.log(Reflect.getMetadata('design:paramtypes', reflected));`
I haven't seen any side effects of this and will update if I find any.